# How to switch two words around in file document in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how to switch two words around in a file document in python. Example: I want to switch the words motorcycle to car, and car to motorcycle.
The way I'm doing it is making it have all the words motorcycle change to car, and because car is being switched to motorcycle, it get's switched back to car. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Please show what have you done to solve this problem.

Comment: To be able to help you we need at least: input date, a snippet of code(what you tried) and an expected result.

Comment: Keep reading word-by-word, if motorcyle, then replace that by car and vice-versa, do not change all the words at once.

Answer (score 2):

First, replace all the `motocycle` to `carholder`

Second, replace all `car` to `motocycle`

Third, replace all `carholder` to `car`

That's it

Comment: its just turning it all to car-holder

Comment: the trick is to change the first string to something unique and easy to replace. I choose `carholder`, but you can change it to something like `my_super_long_and_unique_string_tor_eplace`

Comment: @Tuan Tran means that you need to apply this logic: `aux = a, a = b, b = aux` to change the value of the variables each other. Regards.